# Show a loading gif logo while content is loaded using thread in java swing

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I am trying to show a loading gif inside jlabel while some web request is done. I have done some research and I discovered that I need to use Event dispatch thread in order to do that. But it seems it is putting this task in a queue to execute later. 
I would like to execute in parallel, that means, while the request is done, a gif is showing on screen to inform client that some task is being done.

But this gif only appears after the request is completed.

I have used invokeLater and Swing timer without success. Maybe there is something wrong with my code.

I have this code executed:

```
label.setVisible(true);
label.getParent().revalidate();
label.getParent().repaint();
```

Inside the runnable piece of code.

Am I doing something wrong? Could you please help me?

Comment: You need to do the *other task* in a separate thread, and keep everything Swing on the EDT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `SwingWorker` thread. All swing related things like window paintings and events will execute on EDT. And you will perform background tasks like requesting and retrieving web page in background thread (`SwingWorker`).

API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html

Information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SwingWorker

Comment: Thanks, I have done it, now! The links you provided were excellent.